# Why is this function not returning anything in the interactive shell?

Tags: python, function

When I write this code and then write `add_two_cents(mylist)` into the interactive shell, I am not getting anything back. It just moves on to the next line.

```
mylist = ["kiwi", "apple"]
def add_two_cents(mylist):
  mylist.append("two cents")
```

Comment: Because your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Though it's not formatted as code, it doesn;t appear that your function has a `return` statement, so it wouldn't return anything. You also don't appear to be calling the function anywhere. Can you be more specific about your expectation?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you call the function? The function does not return anything but the mylist variable gets modified.

Comment: `list.append` https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists does not return anything but append an item to an existing list.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning anything so it prints nothing in interpreter.  But lists **are** mutable so you don't have to return if you don't want to, but if you want to see the change you'll need to print the list.  Note I've renamed mylist usage outside the function to make it clear which is a function variable and which is the native variable.

```
def add_two_cents(mylist);
  mylist.append("two cents")
  pass #just to point out end of function


foo = ["kiwi", "apple"]
add_two_cents(foo)
print(str(foo)) # this will print a string representation of foo
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you omit `return` in your function, it's the same as writing `return None`. So your function does return `None` but you don't see that, because by default `None` doesn't show up in the interactive REPL shell. That's why you don't see anything.

Furthermore, if you *want* to see something, you probably want to see your modified list. So you should add `return mylist` at the end of your function.

Finally, as `mylist` is of type `list`, you're changing a mutable and don't really *need* to return the list at all. Just print it again, to see that it changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ["kiwi", "apple"]
def add_two_cents(mylist):
   mylist.append("two cents")
   return mylist
```

You just needed to at the "return" statement